# http post method weird 302 status code when building URI

Tags: flutter

Weird status code 302 is returned when I build url using the variables. But the same code return status code 200 when I don't use variables.

This gives status code 302.

```
static const baseUrl = 'https://******/api'; // hidden on purpose
final http.Client httpClient;
static const apiKey = '******'; // hidden on purpose

String createUrl = '$baseUrl/folder/create?apikey=$apiKey';
    final response = await http.post(createUrl, body: {
      'name': folderName,
      'parent_id': parentId,
    });
```

Whereas the same code when done like below, runs correctly giving status code 200.

```
final url = 'https://******/api/folder/create?apikey=$apiKey';
    final response = await http.post(url, body: {
      'name': folderName,
      'parent_id': parentId,
    });
```

I'm using the flutter http library for POST.

Comment: so you are telling that the first parameter passed to `http.post()` function is the same in both cases?

Comment: @pskink yes they're same

Comment: so with the same input parameters, `http.post()` function returns different status codes??? it is not possible imho...

Comment: @pskink i know. To add to the weirdness, when i call 'get' method for some other api call, it works even when i build the url in the same way i built it for this 'post' method. I'm guessing something's up with the way 'post' method handles it params.

Comment: so what is the output of `var eq = createUrl == url; print('equal $eq);`?

Comment: prints false! Both the text are same I promise you lol @pskink

Comment: no, they are not

Comment: And they weren't! I found the issue. The baseUrl started with `https://website-name.com/api` whereas url was `https://**www**.website-name.com/api`. Aren't `https://google.com` and `https://www.google.com` the same thing??

Comment: of course they are not the same

Comment: Now i know. Thanks for your time. @pskink

Comment: sure, your welcome